# Getting file permission error in docker container ERROR in [eslint] EACCES: permission denied, open '/app/node_modules/.cache/.eslintcache'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker

I am trying to create a react app wihout installing anything in my machine and for that I have used this Dockerfile

```
FROM node:18.12

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["sudo", "npm", "start"]
```

and following is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  ui:
    build: ./ui
    container_name: UI
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - "./ui:/app"
      - "/app/node_modules"
```

when I am doing docker-compose up
I am getting the following error

```
UI  | Failed to compile.
UI  | 
UI  | [eslint] EACCES: permission denied, open '/app/node_modules/.cache/.eslintcache'
UI  | ERROR in [eslint] EACCES: permission denied, open '/app/node_modules/.cache/.eslintcache'
UI  | 
UI  | webpack compiled with 1 error
```

and here's the wsl2 file structure and permissions

```
drwxr-xr-x 5 blank blank   4096 Jan  6 18:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 blank blank   4096 Jan  6 18:54 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 blank blank    310 Jan  6 18:38 .gitignore
-rw-r--r-- 1 blank blank    209 Jan  6 18:55 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 blank blank   3359 Jan  6 18:38 README.md
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  root    4096 Jan  6 18:40 node_modules
-rw-r--r-- 1 blank blank 665979 Jan  6 18:38 package-lock.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 blank blank    827 Jan  6 18:38 package.json
drwxr-xr-x 2 blank blank   4096 Jan  6 18:38 public
drwxr-xr-x 2 blank blank   4096 Jan  6 18:38 src
```

thanks.

Comment: The running application in a container should normally be prohibited from overwriting its own source code; it's very reasonable to get a "permission denied" error writing to the `node_modules` directory.  Can you [install Node](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) instead of installing Docker for this case?  (Is your system otherwise a completely unmodified Windows system, or have you had to install core tools like Git, an IDE, and so on?)

Comment: @DavidMaze I want to use this container as my dev enviroment I dont want to install anything in my host machine (wsl2 ubuntu system) 
and could you explain me about writing own source code part? I dont think I was able to understand that part.

In my opinion it should download the node modules in the attached volume. 

Also yes git and other related stuff are installed.

Comment: A workflow I find works well is to develop my application using host tools, and then package it into a container for integration testing.  This does intrinsically require installing the language runtime (Node) on your host, in the same way you had to install other core tools like your IDE.  I don't feel like it really works to install a desktop OS plus Docker and no other tools.

Comment: but in this case even if i package this and give someone to run the application by doing docker-compose up it wont work they also need to install node in their system right ? which I think defeats the purpose of having docker.

Comment: If you package up the application and give it to someone to run by using `npm run`, they won't need Docker.  Or, you can delete the `volumes:` block and give someone a self-contained Docker image, and they'll need neither Node nor your source code.

Comment: Your goal of no host utils other than git and docker desktop is a fine goal.  No need for sudo in your CMD, the node base image runs as root in the container by default anyway. I guess webpack is running eslint, so I recommend a eslint config file that ignores node_modules anyway as you don't care about those files in linting.

Comment: Other tips:
1. I recommend calling node directly rather than npm in your dockerfile (just put in the command from start in package.json). That's cleaner and helps with stopping the container (assuming you're using an init like tini to capture signals)
2. remove the compose file version line. no versions needed anymore.